# Où se trouve with noun subject

Tags: interrogative, inversion

If I want to ask "Where is my chair?", I used to think I can write: "Où se trouve ma chaise?"

But is this correct formal written French? I learned somewhere that you must use a subject pronoun when using inversion to form a question? For instance: "Quand Monique arrive-t-elle?" *not* "Quand arrive Monique?"

If that is true, then because "ma chaise" is a noun subject, I think I would have to write: "Où ma chaise se trouve-t-elle?"

Are both forms correct in formal written french? Is one "more correct" than the other?

Comment: "Où ma chaise se trouve-t-elle?" doesn't feel right to me, either in spoken, written, informal or formal French. The "se" prevents the use of the construction, IMHO.

Comment: I think this construction in that case is at best on its way out of common usage. Even in formal written French, one could complain it's overly complicated compared to the simpler and perfectly correct "Où se trouve ma chaise?". In the case of _Monique_, the construction doesn't feel surprising, but in the case of the _chaise_, it's a bit jarring. Too many subjects. It may still be correct, but I doubt it's going to survive very long in regular usage.

Comment: "Formal written French" is of little use to a learner. Nobody speaks like that. Real people would say: *Elle se trouve où, ma chaise ?*, *Où elle se trouve, ma chaise ?* and would generally prefer *être* to *se trouver*: *Où elle est/Elle est où/Où c'est qu'elle est/, ma chaise*.

Comment: @jlliagre For sure! But I'm having a hard time with _"Où ma chaise se trouve-t-elle?"_. I'm oscillating between finding it correct and finding it aberrant. Which is it?

Comment: @Frank Probably in between ;-) *Mais où se trouve-t-elle donc, ma foutue chaise ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, if you add something, it sounds more normal. "In between" is what made me think it's "on its way out". But for Monique, no such hesitation. We still process it as completely correct. I attributed the difference to the reflexive "se", but not sure.

Comment: @jlliagre L'expression correcte est _Mais où se trouve-t-elle donc, c'te putain de chaise ?_ ;-) ou bien _Mais où ce qu'elle est, c'te putain de chaise ?_ en français formel, ou bien _Mais où s'k'elle est, c'te putain de chaise ?_ en moins formel.

Comment: @Frank *Mais où que c'est qu'y'est, mon putain de pose-cul ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Cela m'a l'air tout à fait _correct_ aussi.

Comment: @jlliagre Pas mieux, je m'incline ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Se trouver* in this context is another way to express *être*. It's an equals sign, grammatically.  It's impersonal, réciproque, and can be translated like *il y a* depending on context.  « Où se trouve/se trouvent...
? » is a big question for learners and guidebooks because it's useful!

You could say more currently, Mais où est-elle, Monique, elle arrive quand?  Quand est-ce qu'elle arrive ?  Yes, the writing you give gets at least 19/20 from l'Académie but it's not as used in descriptive language. Not wrong, just not used.

Completely okay to ask:

-- Où se trouve ma chaise ? (More formal, written)

-- Ma chaise, elle est où ?

--  Elle est où, ma chaise ?

Either way, you might hear:

-- Ta chaise ?  Cette chaise-ci ? Allez viens, assieds-toi.

[ROBERT](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/trouver): se trouver

> 2. Être (en un endroit, en une circonstance, en présence de). Les personnes qui se trouvent là. Le dossier se trouvait dans un tiroir.
> 3. impersonnel Il se trouve : il existe, il y a. Il se trouve toujours des gens qui disent, pour dire… Il se trouve que : il se fait que. Il
>    se trouve que j'ai raison. ➙ s'avérer. familier Si ça se trouve, se
>    dit pour présenter une éventualité. Si ça se trouve, on nous a
>    oubliés. ➙ peut-être

From the definition with *se trouver* we see the parallel to « Où se trouve ma chaise ? » No need for any other subjects. Elle est où ma chaise ?  Ma chaise, ça se trouve où déjà ?  La réponse, ça se trouve où ?  Dans les commentaires il y en a pas mal.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are correct: Que manges-tu? Que mange Jean?

You can do inversion this way when the verb has no complement, or if the complement is an interrogative adverb. But when there is a complement, you must separate this from the subject when using inversion. For instance: "Que mange le chat?" (what does the cat eat?) follows the simple inversion rule. But if you want to ask "Is the cat eating fish?" you write: "Le chat mange-t-il du poisson?"

It would not have been correct to say "Mange le chat du poisson?", since here the subject and the complement appear directly next to each other.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/6hjzj1/when_does_one_add_pronouns_at_the_end_of_verbs/) (Reddit)

Answer (score -2):

One essential point in adding these redundant pronouns is essentially to ensure that the utterance containing no interrogative word has definitely the form of a question. For instance, in "Pierre fait ses exercices ?" the only device used to make the interlocutor aware that a question is meant is nothing else than an interrogation mark in the text, and the intonation in the spoken language; short of taking in these cues, the reader or hearer can readily decode the utterance as a statement.

In the speech of an experienced and careful speaker, the intonation will be distinctive enough to allow the hearer to make the difference, yet  there is a non-negligible frequency of the occurrences of needed repeats that are made in reason of  the hearer not being quite sure about what he/she has heard; the speaker might then have recourse to the "est-ce que" form for the repetition ("Est-ce que Pierre fait ses exercices ?"). In formal speech it is therefore considered more polite to use the pronoun.

[viveleFle](https://vivelefle.jimdofree.com/niveau-a2/grammaire-a2/les-questions-formelles/)